# Hosting MVC App on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

Could someone please provide me steps or link which explains the detailed process of hosting MVC application on IIS 7.5?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it on my own with help of below link..

[Here is the link](http://codingcluster.blogspot.ca/2012/07/aspnet-mvc-4-and-iis7-how-to.html)

I followed these steps..

**Step 1:** Click start and click Web Platform Installer (WPI)

**Step 2:** Choose tab Products from the top and In the left pane select All.

**Step 3:** Install IIS 7 Recommended Configuration.

**Step 4:** Right click the your project solution (here Firstmvcsite)and select Properties.

**Step 5:** Select Web in the left pane --> Under Servers, select the Use Local IIS Web server radio button --> Select the Create Virtual Directory button.

If you get the message like "Unable to create the virtual directory. To access Web sites on the local IIS Web server, you must run Visual Studio under an Administrator account".

Just click start --> find Visual Studio --> right click and Run as Administrator.

Now you do the Step 5 again you will get success message.

**Step 6:**  Go to start --> Run --> type inetmgr, and go to Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager  and drill down in the Default Web Site and choose your site(here Firstmvcsite) and select Browse *:80(http) in the right pane.